# MS Access report to PDF cuts of some characters inconsistently

Tags: ms-access, pdf-generation

My print preview from MS Access shows everything perfectly fine. [Here's the actual PDF file snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaC7E.png) which shows some letters are cut in half. It happens inconsistently with this report and not always for the same data.

In this report only 5 out of 40 questions had their first letter cut in half.
Please advise.

I've tried adjusting where the data field must start, i.e. I've moved the start of the question a bit more right, but no difference.

[Here's the design view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQP2n.png) I've highlighted in yellow where the question starts. I've moved it more right, makes no difference.

[Here's where the user captures questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppLqs.png)]

Comment: As a workaround, adding a few mm to `LeftMargin` or `LeftPadding` might help. Do you have any code in the Format event of the report? Can you add a screenshot of the report in design view?

Comment: I've attached the design view in my main question thanks. LeftMargin and Padding doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Hm. Nothing stands out as suspicious. Can you share a stripped-down version of your database that still shows the behaviour?

Comment: As a real crude workaround you can try using something like `="  " & [Question]` as controlsource for the textbox.

Comment: Sure - how do I share it?

Comment: Just upload to a file hoster of your choice (e.g. http://www.filedropper.com/ ) and post the link here.

Comment: [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15108138/CSC%20APSC%201%20MCQ%2016.xls) This Excel file gets imported and a new temp table is created with the data. The report then uses the temporary table to print from there.

Comment: The xls data doesn't help to reproduce the problem, I meant the Access database (your mdb or accdb containing the report).

Comment: [Here it is](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15108138/ExaminerObe%20stripped.mdb) 
Reports and LDL > Print loaded exam paper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem text lines have a stray Tab character (ASCII 9) at or near the beginning of the line, which is being interpreted as a lateral positioning move for the string. Your correct lines do not have a stray Tab. If you use Acrobat's text editor to delete the Tab, the rest of the line jumps properly into view.

Below, I've extracted the text of each line in your sample, and replaced the unexpected Tab character with an "**X**." If you use Acrobat text editing to navigate carefully to the spot in the line where the Tab is located (you won't see it directly, but it's there), Shift-cursor sideways to highlight the Tab alone, and delete it, you'll see the text revert to its normal appearance.

Note that the Tab is usually *not* the first character in the line, in lines where it appears:

> S**X**ources of polyunsaturated fats include
>
> L**X**ack of calcium is one of the major causes of osteoporosis
>
> **X**Disaccharides are the simplest form of carbohydrate
>
> Excessive long term protein intake may lead to kidney problems
>
> Water soluble vitamins taken in excess have toxic effects in the body
>
> L**X**ack of calcium is one of the major causes of osteoporosis
>
> S**X**ources of polyunsaturated fats include
>
> V**X**itamin B12 is involved in

I'm going to hazard a guess here that the problem was introduced in the text before it was uploaded to your final document, so that the unwanted Tabs somehow snuck in as body text. I hope that helps.

Comment: Brilliant. What would we do with out clever people like you guys. I went to the form where db questions are captured. Deleted the questions in question :) and re-typed it by hand. Worked perfectly. I think the user copied the question from a PDF manual which added the hidden tab character. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That is one weird effect. It is a bit suspicious that it only occurs towards the end of the document, but I have no idea what causes it.

Two workarounds worked for me:

1) Use

```
="  " & [Question]
```

as control source of the text box, and rename it to `txtQuestion` to avoid a circular reference. That's two spaces, one wasn't enough.

Move it a bit to the left, to make up for the increased indentation.

---

2) Don't use the Access-integrated PDF creator, use a PDF printer instead.

I used the Windows 10 integrated "Microsoft Print to PDF", but there are many free ones, e.g. https://en.pdf24.org/ (just google "pdf printer driver").

This created a larger .pdf file for me, but it doesn't show the error.

---

**Edit:** Interestingly, while Adobe Acrobat Reader shows the error, Foxit Reader or the Firefox integrated PDF viewer doesn't. [Here is a single page example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25769639/ExamQuestionsPg7.pdf) if anyone else wants to check.

Comment: Thanks so much! And thanks for the detailed response.